# How can I iterate through the "keywords" array of this object to return an array of only keywords?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I can console log one keyword at a time using the forEach method as below, but can't figure out how to return an array of all keywords from the JSON at the bottom. I hope to generate the array for a bar chart of values for each keyword. The keywords will form the Y axis, and the values the X axis in a d3.js visualization.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  keywords = d.keywords
  console.log(keywords[0][0]);// "white"
});

{
        "title": "I'm Dreaming of a White Christmas",
        "artist": "Bing Crosby",
        "year": "1942",
        "sales": "50,000,000",
        "keywords": [
            [
                "white",
                6
            ],
            [
                "Christmas",
                6
            ],
            [
                "dreaming",
                4
            ],
            [
                "christmases",
                2
            ],
            [
                "merry",
                2
            ],
            [
                "write",
                2
            ],
            [
                "snow",
                2
            ],
            [
                "sleigh",
                2
            ],
            [
                "listen",
                2
            ],
            [
                "glisten",
                2
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your data variable is your json object. If so, and if you want to get an array of all keywords (first element) you can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in this way:

```js
var data = {
    "title": "I'm Dreaming of a White Christmas",
    "artist": "Bing Crosby",
    "year": "1942",
    "sales": "50,000,000",
    "keywords": [
        [
            "white",
            6
        ],
        [
            "Christmas",
            6
        ],
        [
            "dreaming",
            4
        ],
        [
            "christmases",
            2
        ],
        [
            "merry",
            2
        ],
        [
            "write",
            2
        ],
        [
            "snow",
            2
        ],
        [
            "sleigh",
            2
        ],
        [
            "listen",
            2
        ],
        [
            "glisten",
            2
        ]
    ]
};
var keywords = data.keywords.map(function(d) {
    return d[0];
});

console.log(keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty array to store the results. Then, loop through the array of keywords, pushing the first element of each to the results array:

```
let results = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.keywords.forEach( function(keyword) {
    results.push( keyword[0] ); // "white"
  });
});
console.log( results );
```